# My website looks slighty different on my phone compared to my computer

Tags: html, css

I edited css of my website to make it responsive, but it looks completly different on my phone compared to my computer.

[This is a screenshot from built-in firefox responsive design view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf8sZ.png)

[This one comes from my phone. It looks more stretched, especially when you look at text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98cYm.png)

CSS code that is responible for page responsibility:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1300px) {

  .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .header {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 40px 0;
  }

  .logo {
    zoom: 0.7;
    -moz-transform: scale(0.7);
    padding: 30
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  .logo > img {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  .nav {
    width: 100%;
    /*font-size: 60px;*/
    padding: 10px 0;
    background-color: #30415d;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px solid #8eaebd;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #8eaebd;
  }

  ol {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    height: auto;
    line-height: 200%;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  ol > li {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
    /*height: 50px;*/
    border-right: 1px solid #8eaebd;
  }

  .content {
    width: 95%;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: justify;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }

  .socials {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #292929;
  }

  .socialdivs {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  .fb {
    width: 25%;
    height: 155px;
    float:left;
  }

  .yt {
    width: 25%;
    height: 155px;
    float:left;
  }

  .tw {
    width: 25%;
    height: 155px;
    float:left;
  }

  .gplus {
    width: 25%;
    height: 155px;
    float:left;
  }

  .

}
```

I tried to increase the font to look bigger on phone screen with no effect. I also tried to add `<br>` tag to separate this sentence but text still looks to small on phones.

Comment: Can provide to us your code.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your html head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

A `meta viewport` element gives the browser instructions on how to control the page's dimensions and scaling.

The `width=device-width` part sets the width of the page to follow the screen-width of the device (which will vary depending on the device).

The  part sets the initial zoom level when the page is first loaded by the browser.

Comment: That worked a little. It left me with a big margin on the right side of my website. However this happens only on my phone browser. On PC website looks far better, even in responsive design view

Comment: Is there a big space on the right, or can you scroll right on your mobile?

Comment: I can scroll my page horizontally. I'm giving up with this. For now it will be only desktop friendly. I will add responsive design when I will learn more of HTML and CSS. At the moment I know basics of them.

Comment: If you can scroll your page horizontally, it means that there is an element taking more space than there is available on the screen. Begin debugging your css, take some elements out and see if it fixes your problem.  Take a look at bootstrap for easier mobile development - www.getbootstrap.com